# angular-sanitize: Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] on Angular 1.2.1

Tags: angularjs

I installed `angular-sanitize#1.2.3` in `Angular 1.2.1` with Yeoman Generator:

`index.html`:

```
...
<!-- build:js scripts/modules.js -->
  <script src="bower_components/angularjs-geolocation/src/geolocation.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>

  <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

  <script src="bower_components/ngprogress/build/ngProgress.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
...
```

`app.js:`

```
...
angular.module('angularGeolocationApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngRoute',
  'geolocation',
  'pascalprecht.translate',
  'ngProgress',
  'ngStorage',
  'ngSanitize'
])
...
```

Without even injecting `$sanitize`, I get:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

angular-sanitize v1.2.3 is incompatible with AngularJS v1.2.1
The latest version of $sanitize (1.2.3) now uses the same mechanism as `$compile` to validate uris, which uses the new private service $$sanitizeUri that is only part of AngularJS v1.2.3 and up. See this [commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/333523483f3ce6dd3177b697a5e5a7177ca364c8#diff-9719fa4d66ff667c572d690fb66c5de2) for more information.

To resolve, either install angular-sanitize v1.2.1 or upgrade AngularJS to 1.2.3

Answer (score 0):

It looks you have everything necessary to run without exception. The only thing I can suggest is to check everywhere else you use `angular.module('angularGeolocationApp'...)` to make sure you are not accidentally overriding the dependencies. Just make sure you only have one instance with the second parameter defined.

Comment: I'm completly lost. Commenting out `ngSanitize` in the dependencies array fixes the issue. I checked all my other modules but none of them defines the argument's array.